# Hooking up two external monitors with windows 10

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10

So I have just purchased a laptop and two external HDMI monitors and a HDMI splitter. I hooked up the monitors to the laptop and went into windows 10 display settings to open the monitors to run the 3 monitor set up. I can only get the laptop screen and the 2nd monitor to project to both external monitors. I look further into the settings and notice that the laptop is using the internal GPU to drive the displays and not using the Nvidia 940M that is in the laptop. All drivers are up to date, and I am not sure how to get this problem solved. **Any suggestions on what I can do to get this to work?** If I am unable to run 3 monitors with the cards that I have, I am just fine running the two external monitors and shutting off the laptop screen, but I have no clue how to do this with windows 10.

[Laptop Description](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/hp-envy-17-3-touch-screen-laptop-intel-core-i7-16gb-memory-1tb-hard-drive-linear-carbon-natural-silver/4221700.p?id=1219708600772&skuId=4221700&cmp=RMX)

Comment: Please define exactly what you mean by "HDMI splitter" (make and model if possible). If it's a true "splitter" then it will appear as a single monitor to the computer.

Comment: http://www.bestbuy.com/site/rocketfish-2-way-hdmi-splitter-silver/1224493.p?id=1218238810316&skuId=1224493 is the link for the splitter they recommended

Comment: Using a HDMI splitter will just duplicate what is displayed across two monitors. Is that what you want?  Based on your hardware it is unlikely you will be able to run three independent monitors.

Comment: No I want the two external monitors to be separate. Even if that means turning off the laptop screen. The laptop I have only has one HDMI hookup, is it even possible to do what I am suggesting? Take a look at the laptop description in the initial question

Comment: I'd like to try this too, unfortunately my GPU only has a single hdmi port on the back.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible. To connect two monitors, you need two outputs. If you have a VGA output as well you could (probably) connect a 3rd monitor there. Turning off the laptop screen wouldn't help.

Comment: Does the laptop have a DisplayPort? DisplayPort can be daisy-chained to multiple monitors.

Comment: No displayport, just one HDMI.